# Mark an item with a particular category

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to mark an item with a particular category, based on the text within the item.

I have the following code.

```
Sub ProcessRSS()
    ' Read RSS items and process the usful ones.
    Dim objList As Object
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim iCount As Integer

    Set objList = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
    iCount = 0

    For Each objItem In objList
        If (InStr(objItem.Body, "(WA)") > 0) Then
            objItem.Categories = "Important"
            If (InStr(objItem.Categories, "Important") > 0) Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print "Marked " & iCount & " RSS Items as important."

End Sub
```

I select the folder and then run the macro, but it won't mark the category.

Comment: Why do you check if objItem.Categories contains "Important" after you **just set** the Categories to "Important"? Why not just increase the item count after setting the Categories Property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `.Save` your item after you update the category.  Below is your For loop with the save.  As a side note, keep in mind that you'll be overwriting any existing categories as `.Categories` is a comma-delimited string.  You may want to test if `.Categories` is empty and, if not, add ", Important".

```
For Each objItem In objList
    If (InStr(objItem.Body, "(WA)") > 0) Then
        objItem.Categories = "Important"
        objItem.Save
        If (InStr(objItem.Categories, "Important") > 0) Then
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believe it was so difficult to find out that simple bit of information I needed. Thankyou very much!