# Convert RSS feed items to tasks in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, task, outlook-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Processing an RSS Feed using Outlook VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439187/processing-an-rss-feed-using-outlook-vba-macro)

I receive my homework through RSS Feed and I want to be able to convert feed items to tasks.

How do I get the RSS feed in VBA? I cannot find an "RSSItem", but I can find a TaskItem.

I've tried getting the RSS feed through the method below but I cant put the body of the feed item into a string. It won't even let me find the length of the string. I receive an "Invalid Qualifier" error when I run it.

```
Sub ProcessRSS()
' Read RSS items and process the usful ones.
Dim objList As Object
Dim objItem As Object
Dim contents As String

Set objList = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
contents = objList(1).Body

'Print Lenght of String
MsgBox (Str(contents.Lenght))
End Sub
```

How can I convert an RSS feed item to a task in Outlook 2010 VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your overall question, but this fixes your code above:

```
Sub ProcessRSS()
' Read RSS items and process the usful ones.
Dim objItem As Object

Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items(1)
'Print Length of String
MsgBox Len(objItem.Body)
End Sub
```